# ios pubnub messaging system

Tags: ios, ios7, pubnub

I am using pubnub in an ios app and have come accross a bump in the development process. I have setup a social network where a user can register, have their own profile, add/remove friends..etc. I have also been able to implement a system where a user can chat 1on1 with whatever friend they choose to chat with from their friends list using pubnub. All of the apps friend and user data is accessed from a php/mysql backend that is retrieved via json. I am now trying to implement an alert message system that lets a user send a message that is immediately recieved by everyone on that user's friendslist. The AlertMessageView would simply contain a textfield and a button. When a user inputs a message and presses the submit button it will use the pubnub messaging system to send the message to everyone. Is there anyone that may have an idea as to how this can be done? Is it possible? I am lost and need guidance regarding the implementation of such functionality. Let me know if there is any code that you would like to see. Thanks in advance.

Idea of functionality (every user will be able to do this).

- user inputs message
- user presses submit button
- json used to retrieve a list of everyone on that user's friends list
- ??how to implement pubnub sending message to all users on friends list??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods of specific interest to you are:

https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c/tree/master/iOS#publishing-messages (publishing messages)

and

https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c/tree/master/iOS#who-is-here-now- (getting a list of users)

You should use the pattern where each user listens on his own channel (myUsername-private), and can also subscribe to a public lobby (public) channel. This way, he can get messages on public and his private channels.

Public chat traffic is received on public channel, and private chat dialog is exchanged on private channels.

The demo app located at https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c/tree/master/iOS/iPadDemoApp has a pretty good example of using each of the methods you are looking for.

Also, have you had a chance to checkout the formal docs and tutorial available at http://www.pubnub.com/docs/objective-c/iOS/ios-sdk.html ? I think it will show you how to accomplish everything you need in PubNub. From there, its just a matter of integrating the iOS calls with it.

geremy

Comment: Thanks a lot, it will take me some time to go through all of this and implement it, but information is all I needed.